# Replace sequence of non-alphabet with one dash using Pattern

Tags: java

*What I am trying to achieve:*

I have a string that looks like this: `��[1]����important?@~?@~?@~?@~?@~alsoimportant�@~@~@~`

Basically, inside the string, there are words (composed of only the alphabet) with gibberish (one or multiple non-alphabet) before and after.

I would like to retain the alphabet with the sequence of non-alphabet replaced by one dash only. If possible, use Java Pattern, because it is quite efficient.

*What I tried:*

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
        final String input = "��[1]����important?@~?@~?@~?@~?@~alsoimportant�@~@~@~";
        final String clean = input.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "-");
        System.out.println(clean);
        // print ---------important---------------alsoimportant-------
        // would like -important-alsoimportant-
    }
```

*Question:*

With my current solution:

- It is not using Pattern
- there are a number of dashes equal to the number of non-alphabet. I just need one.
  What is a good way to achieve this?

Comment: *`"I would like to retain the alphabet with the sequence of non-alphabet replaced by one dash only. If possible, use Java Pattern, because it is quite efficient."`*  Why not just show the resultant string instead of describing it?

Comment: To me, that looks more like a string that has been badly en/decoded. IOW it has missing data. So how do you know those data are not also important?

Comment: *"`If possible, use Java Pattern, because it is quite efficient.`"* Actually, Java Pattern is not necessarily efficient but it provides general convenience.  In  some situations where performance is critical, writing a custom parser would probably be better.  But that also depends on the complexity of the parser and coding time.

Comment: `s.replaceAll("\\p{alpha}", "-")` will do it for you, if you really don't care about the encoding issue I mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `+` quantifier in your regular expression to match 1+ consecutive non-alphabet characters:

```java
 final String input = "��[1]����important?@~?@~?@~?@~?@~alsoimportant�@~@~@~";
 final String clean = input.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "-"); 
 System.out.println(clean); // prints -important-alsoimportant-
```

Similar goes for the Pattern (might be helpful if you're doing this replacement multiple times):

```java
final Pattern NON_ALPHABET = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z]+");
final String input = "��[1]����important?@~?@~?@~?@~?@~alsoimportant�@~@~@~";
final String clean = NON_ALPHABET.matcher(input).replaceAll("-");
System.out.println(clean); // prints the same
```

Comment: upd: there is good practice to to store pattern as a static variable, just a side note

Comment: @PatPanda You haven't actually accepted the answer.  Click on the check mark to the left.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way if you focus on the words. I'd like to use `Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+")` to solve the problem. After getting the expected words, say, "important" and "alsoimportant", it is convenient to use StringBuilder to join them together.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "��[1]����important?@~?@~?@~?@~?@~alsoimportant�@~@~@~";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("-");
        while (matcher.find()) {
            builder.append(matcher.group()).append("-");
        }
        System.out.println(builder); // output "-important-alsoimportant-"
    }
}
```

Note: The pattern above assumes that all of the words consist only of letters from 'a' to 'z' or 'A' to 'Z'. Yet some of the words, like "mp3" would be regarded as the combination of the word "mp" and gibberish '3'. To avoid this, just change the pattern to `Pattern.compile("\\w+")`.

Answer (score 1):

As I have said before, regular expressions, like streams, are a good general tool but not always as efficient as imperative programming. The following was about 37% more efficient that using `String.replaceAll`

```
boolean seen = false;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
    if (!Character.isAlphabetic(c)) {
        if (!seen) {
            sb.append("-");
            seen = true;
        }
    } else {
        sb.append(c);
        seen = false;
    }
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

Although the time differences were significant, the time required was very small. As such it wouldn't really make a big difference in this particular problem and I would have probably opted for `String.replaceAll` myself.

Answer (score -1):

> *"It is not using Pattern"*

It is, actually.
The *[String#replaceAll](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#L2964)* method is utilizing the *Pattern* class.

> *"there are a number of dashes equal to the number of non-alphabet. I just need one. What is a good way to achieve this?"*

The effect you're looking to achieve can be done with the *[+ quantifer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Basic_concepts)*.
This will attempt to match *1 or more* of the the preceding value, in this case the *character class*.

```java
final String input = "��[1]����important?@~?@~?@~?@~?@~alsoimportant�@~@~@~";
final String clean = input.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "-");
System.out.println(clean);
// print ---------important---------------alsoimportant-------
// would like -important-alsoimportant-
```

Output

```
-important-alsoimportant-
```

If you'd like to implement the *[Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)* and *[Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)* classes explicitly, you can use the following.

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z]+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll("-"));
```

Output

```
-important-alsoimportant-
```